# Access Violation in Marshal.PtrToStructure

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I am trying to deserialize a structure, and I'm getting an AV exception in PtrToStructure. The only wrinkle is that this is a variable length structure, so I need to adjust the length before deserializing. Here's my code, is there anything obviously wrong? The structure contains only integer/short/byte arrays, nothing fancy.

the incoming data is 374 bytes, and I need to adjust it to match the 576 bytes data structure. Basically the incoming packet has a shorter last field than the max possible, which is normal.

```
public static ... FromByteArray(byte[] receivedData)
    {
        int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyPacket));
    // allocate a new buffer of the maximum size, to help deserialization
    byte[] newBuffer = new byte[rawsize]; 
    Array.Copy(receivedData, newBuffer, receivedData.Length);

    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
    Marshal.Copy(newBuffer, 0, buffer, rawsize);

/// CRASHES ON NEXT LINE
    MyPacketDefinition def = (MyPacketDefinition ) Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(MyPacketDefinition ));   
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);

    //...
}
```

My structure looks something like this:

```
 [StructLayout (LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack=1, Size=576, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
 public struct MyPacket
    {

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public System.Byte Type;

    .
    . // a few more INT/SHORT fields
    .

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        [FieldOffset(28)]  public System.Byte[] Address;


        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst=64)]
        [FieldOffset(44)] public System.String Name;


        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        [FieldOffset(108)] public System.String SystemData;


        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 340)]
        [FieldOffset(236)] public System.Byte[] Options;

}
```

With the last parameter (Option) being a variable length field of maximum 340 bytes (normally shorter)

Comment: That's probably a typo, but shouldn't you use MyPacket instead of MyData when calling Marshal.PtrToStructure?

Comment: Why not just use BinaryReader, since you know all the offsets? You're basically copying memory around and transition from managed to unmanaged memory just to convert receivedData byte array to the structure that, judging by the code here, isn't being used by unmanaged code at all (since you FreeHGlobal immediately after PtrToStructure).

Comment: Yes, it was a typo i introduced when simplifying the code for posting. Sorry about that! i fixed it.

I will try out the BinaryReader, but I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong above. :)

Comment: What does the structure really look like?  Unless I misunderstand it, the MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr) seems to imply that it contains pointers to strings as opposed to containing a statically-sized character array.

Comment: Why are you using LayoutKind.Explicit? As you are defining all the field's sizes, you could just use LayoutKind.Sequential, and drop all the FieldOffsets. Less prone to errors.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but....

In order to use C# marshalling with arrays inside structs you have to declare them as "fixed", otherwise they are just pointers out to managed memory which will make a mess.

Its worth noting that "fixed" for some reason is an unsafe option and requires you flag your code as unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using this method, as suggested by Franci in the comments (although I'm not sure if this is what he meant).

I do not know why the other way was raising an AV, I've used that method before with no issues.

```
    byte[] mem = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyPacketDefinition))];
    Marshal.Copy(receivedData, 0, mem, mem.Length);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(mem))
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms))
        {
            byte[] buff = br.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyPacketDefinition )));

            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buff, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            try
            {
                MyPacketDefinition s = (MyPacketDefinition )Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(MyPacketDefinition ));
            }
            finally
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
            
        }
   }
```

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. You're using the sizeof operator on a Type which isn't allowed (I guess you meant Marshal.SizeOf instead).  And you've reversed the arguments to Array.Copy so you're basically zeroing out receivedData. Even if you fix that the content of buff will always be identical to that of mem. I believe the problem with your original code was incorrectly using LPStr where it should have been ByValTStr.

Comment: Thank you. I just had a notification after.. uh.. 12 years, and yes, the code was wrong. I hope i fixed it correctly above, without testing. It was probably some hacking night. It was obviously diverged from the code I was trying to fix.